# Within Matlab GUI, I want to transfer the selected data in listbox1 to listbox2

Tags: matlab, user-interface, listbox

This case is, I know how to transfer all the data from one listbox to another one, and then clear listbox1. I did in this way:
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

StringInLB1 = get(handles.listbox1,'string');

set(handles.listbox2,'string',StringInLB1);

set(handles.listbox1,'string','');

Now my question is: How can I transfer some selected data to listbox2 ? I "ctrl+ single click" multiple data in listbox1, but how can I use thoes data?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looking to assign some function to the listbox callback. i.e. each time the selection is changed by the user, you want to do something with the data. Anyhow that's what I understood from your comment to @James answer.

If it's the case, here is a sample code generating a simple GUI in which the color of a plot is changed by the user directly by clicking in the listbox:

```
function DummyListBox

global hFig hListBox hPlot
ScreenSize = get(0,'ScreenSize');

hFig = figure('Visible','off','Position',[ScreenSize(3)/2,ScreenSize(4)/2,450,285]);

ColorString = {'Red';'Green';'Blue'}; % Define string populating the listbox

hListBox = uicontrol('Style','Listbox','String',ColorString,'Position',[315,150,70,50],'max',3,...
    'min',1,'Callback',@ListBox_Callback); %%// added 'min' and 'max' properties to select multiple items

hText = uicontrol('Style','Text','Position',[315,220,70,35],'String','Empty now'); %%// Add text box

hAxes = axes('Units','Pixels','Position',[50,60,200,185]);

set(hFig,'Visible','on')

x = 1:5*pi;
hPlot = plot(x,sin(x),'-r','Parent',hAxes); %display some data

    % Listbox callback: each time the selection changes, the color of the
    % plot changes accordingly.
    function ListBox_Callback(~,~)

       SelectedValues = get(hListBox,'Value'); % Get the values selected

    set(hText,'String',SelectedValues); % Uptdate the string in the textbox

    NewColor = ColorString{get(hListBox,'Value')};
    set(hPlot,'Color',NewColor)
    end

end
```

The output now looks like this:

[image]

As you see the function in which the change in color takes place is the listbox's callback. Hope this is what you want. If not please be more specific as to what you would like. Thanks!

**EDIT:** As you can see, I added a text box to show you what it looks like when you select multilpe items in the listbox. In order to do so, you must add a 'min' and a 'max' property when you create the listbox. I set them to 1 and 3, respectively. The 'Value' property of the listbox corresponds to the actual number of the item selected from the list. So if you have 3 items as is my exmample,the Value can be 1,2,3 or any combination. They are displayed in the text box. You can get the corresponding data from those values, stored in vectors.

So to answer your question, you could write:

```
Data1 = ValuesVector(1)
Data2 = VectorValues(2)
... and so on
```

Comment: You got what I mean. Now I know how to use the selected data.Here is my code:list_entries = get(handles.listbox1,'String');
        index_selected = get(handles.listbox1,'Value'); % although i             dont how what exactly this 'value' mean here.
        var1 = list_entries{index_selected(1)}; % var1 and var 2 are the data user select. Here comes the question, in your case, you only need to select one option, red, green or blue, so you  need to do one step. But what if a user select ten data? I must write var1=..., var2=.....var10=?

Comment: Hi, I have solved the problem and thanks for your help. I will vote for your answer.

Comment: alright I just updated my answer! This is probably what you were looking for. Thanks for the vote!

Comment: This updated answer is really what I need. Now I know the meaning of 'value'. (I am new to GUI, my manager let me do this). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great then glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a

```
tmp = get(handles.listbox1,'string');
```

You'll see what the variable is like. Then you can use something like

```
set(handles.listbox1,'string',tmp{2});
```

Comment: yeah, I know. But the thing is: a user will operate this UI, he will just click on some data and a push button. Do you know how to use the data by only clicking and selecting them?